# Intersection of two Sorted Linked Lists C++

Tags: c++

I have some troubles with my intersection method. It works properly, but after end of programm it throws mistakes. Here`s my code:

```
void SortedLinkedList::intersection(SortedLinkedList finalList, SortedLinkedList list1, SortedLinkedList list2) {
        Node *pointer1 = list1.first;
        Node *pointer2 = list2.first;
        int counter = 0;
        while (pointer1 != NULL && pointer2 != NULL) {
            if (pointer1->data < pointer2->data) {
                pointer1 = pointer1->next;
            }
            else if (pointer2->data < pointer1->data){
                pointer2 = pointer2->next;
            }
            else if (pointer1->data == pointer2->data){
                finalList.addItem(pointer1->data);
                pointer1 = pointer1->next;
                pointer2 = pointer2->next;
            }
        }
        finalList.printList();
    }
```

I need to get intersection of two lists in a third one.

Comment: What does "throws mistakes" mean, and what are they? Memory leaks? Please post any output that appears.

Comment: probably would need whole definition of class and ..by style of your code it looks very underdeveloped in nature.  And throw? throw is particular term relted to exceptions. Maybe you want ru.stackoverflow  if you have issues with language barrier

Comment: Please show us the error.

Comment: Off-topic, but generally, you should use keywords instead of macros, here specifically: `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. For pointers, it is quite common just to check `if(pointer)`, you might prefer it (you should for booleans, just for completeness...).

Comment: The final if is obsolete, if neither `a < b` nor `b < a`, then `a == b` (unless you do not have a *total* order, but then you'd have to handle != as well, which might get the really complex case...)

Comment: What, if your `finalList` is not empty when passed? User's problem? *Possibly* better design: `SortedList intersect(SortedList const& x, SortedList const& y)`. With appropriate move constructor, you shouldn't have to fear too much overhead returning by value (well, with linked list, you shouldn't have to at all...).

Comment: @Aconcagua good point, and because this is a method..is this a static or not? shouldn't `this` be one of operands? I think, OP is confused by multitude of possible architecture choices

Comment: @Aconcagua what if both data are floating points and there is chance that they are nan? all comparisons but `!=` may yield false (IEEE 754), that is `==` will not help here, only `!=` would

Comment: Have you considered [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?

Comment: @Swift 1.: recommending static or free-standing function 2.: nan -> no total order any more...

Answer (score 1):

Main glaring mistake: `SortedLinkedList finalist`
You have to change values in  that class, it's your output data structure. You have to pass it by reference, otherwise the actual list passed to the function never will be changed.

In some cases you would like other input data passed refs too, just if you do it with "const" declarator, you have to use only `const` methods from them. As you actually do not use any methods andyour class is relatively simple, that doesn't matter much

```
void SortedLinkedList::intersection(SortedLinkedList& finalList, 
                  const SortedLinkedList& list1,
                  const SortedLinkedList& list2)
```

Anything else without seeing whole design of your class would be guesswork. problem might be in your AddItem method or in lack of class fields initialization.

Comment: SortedLinkedList SortedLinkedList::intersection(const SortedLinkedList& list1, const SortedLinkedList& list2, SortedLinkedList& finalList) {
    Node *p1 = list1.first;
    Node *p2 = list2.first;
    while(p1 != NULL && p2 != NULL) {
        if (p1->data == p2->data) {
            finalList.addItem(p1->data);
            p1 = p1->next;
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
        else if (p1->data < p2->data)
            p1 = p1->next;
        else
            p2 = p2->next;
    }
    return finalList;

}
I did like this

Answer (score 0):

The standard library offer a method for that [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

It is precisely used to merge to sorted containers.

This is the snippet taken from the link:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  std::vector<int> v2{        5,  7,  9,10};
  std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
  std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

  std::vector<int> v_intersection;

  std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                        v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
  for(int n : v_intersection)
    std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

In the link you will find a couple of possible implementations as well. But, my suggestion is: "Don't reinvent the wheel, just realign it".